# Creating a date validator

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to write a date validator that will take a date entered as a string of length 8 in the format ddmmyyyy. It needs to check it for all the basics for a valid date, and return either true or false as a result.

I am unable to use an additional library such as moment and I cannot use regular expressions (this is not a homework assignment, I'm just being told to work within these constraints).

I'd appreciate it if people could tell me what's wrong with what I have below!

```
function isValidDate(i) {

    if (i.length == 8) {
        var dd = i.substring(0, 2);
        var mm = i.substring(2, 4);
        var yyyy = i.substring(4, 7);
        var day = parseInt(dd,10);
        var month = parseInt(mm,10);
        var year = parseInt(yyyy,10);
        if (year % 4 != 0 && day = 29 && month = 02) {
            return false;
        } else if (day > 31) {
            return false;
        } else if (month > 12) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: after you splitted your string into variables `yyyy`,`mm`,`dd` you can create a new Date object from that data and check if Date object has the same variables which has been pased into creating Date object.

Comment: Your function allows day = 31 for months that only have 30 days

Comment: It also allows February 30 and February 31, but not Feb 29 except in leap years (but it doesn't know about the century rule for leap years).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such function. This function checks if provided arguments is valid integer numbers (via parsing them to integer and checking if they not NaN) and then checks if month and days are valid, but doesn't validates year because year can be any number :)

```
function dateValidation(year, month, day){
   // Check arguments
   year = parseInt(year);
   if (isNaN(year)) return false;

   month = parseInt(month);
   if (isNaN(month)) return false;

   day = parseInt(day);
   if (isNaN(day)) return false;

   // Check if month is correct
   if (!(month >= 1 && month <= 12)) return false;

   switch (month){
      case 1: //January
      case 3: // March
      case 5: // May
      case 7: // July
      case 8: // Augyst
      case 10:// October
      case 12:// December
          return (day > 0 && day <= 31); // Maximum days is 31 in these months
          break
      case 4: // April
      case 6: // June
      case 9: // September
      case 11:// November
          return (day > 0 && day <= 30); // Maximum days is 30 in these months
          break
      case 2: // February
          if (year % 4 != 0){
              return (day > 0 && day <= 28);
          } else {
              return (day > 0 && day <= 29);
          break
            }
      default:
          return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, the use of cases is very helpful.

Comment: Not with my reputation I can't apparently!

Answer (score 1):

Your first misstake is to use = instead of == in comparisation.

The next one is to use 02 as integer which is not possible because parseInt would make 2 out of 02 so just compare == 2

```
if (year % 4 != 0 && day == 29 && month == 2) {
```

An assignment will always return true in an if statement and year % 4 is not 0 in 2014 so you will always end up in "return false" until 2016